# Need to replace integers with floating points in lines containing a specific string in an xml formatted file

Tags: bash, xslt, awk, sed

For reasons related to app functionality, we need to massage certain data incoming to a system by replacing an integer value with a fixed length decimal value

Example:

Before

```
<smile:ordinary code:type="Fields" code:value="25">
```

After

```
<smile:ordinary code:type="Fields" code:value="25.000000000">`
```

I had tried to used a sed command in place to replace with a regex group such as the one below

```
sed -i 's/\(ordinary.*"[0-9]\+\)/\1.000000000/'
```

This works fine but there's a file watcher that triggers when the file is modified and if it receives a well formatted file, it ends up adding an extra set of 0s

```
<smile:ordinary code:type="Fields" code:value="25.000000000.000000000">
```

I've also struggled to get this working with awk and printf but ideally, i'd replace the integer strictly with a decimal. I've considered using an xsl filter transform as well but I'm not quite as well versed there as with shell commands. I'm open to all suggestions including possibly writing a shell script to loop through each line I guess.

Comment: I don't think it matters how you do it. No matter what you do, the watcher is going to break it by adding more zeroes.

Comment: Why is the watcher adding zeroes if the file is already formatted properly?

Comment: That pattern is dangerous, as it will mangle, for instance,  `<smile:ordinary code:type="Fields" someOther="10" code:value="25">`.  If you're POSITIVE the structure will never include other numeric fields, you could look for `[^\.]` at the end to prevent finding a number that is already floating point.

Comment: It's generally fragile and unreliable to transform XML files with non-XML-aware tools such as `sed`. I think your suggestion of an XSLT filter is a better idea. It would be a trivial stylesheet, and I'm sure you could get the help you need here. What are the namespace URIs bound to the prefix `smile` and `code`?

Comment: How about fixing the bug in the file watcher`?

Comment: So... you're not asking how to change your file, you're asking how to stop the "watcher" from also changing the file, is that right?

Comment: I think i will stick to xslt yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easily done in XSLT. It just needs a stylesheet with two rules, the standard identity template that copies elements unchanged by default plus a rule

```
<xsl:template match="smile:ordinary/@code:value">
  <xsl:attribute name="code:value">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.000000000')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Plus the required namespace declarations, of course.

Comment: I think i'll stick to xslt yeah